# Looping to calculate False Acceptance Rate (FAR) in python

Tags: python, pandas

Now, I am working to calculate False Acceptance Rate (FAR). I have a dataset that are collected from 5 person. To calculate FAR, we can use formula following below:

```
FAR = Number acceptance of impostors / total number of impostors
```

In this case I compare the template and testing data by using euclidean distance like following below to obtain the number acceptance of importors:

**stage 1**

```
 person 1 -->    person 2
                 person 3
                 person 4
                 person 5
```

**stage 2**

```
person 2 -->    person 1
                person 3
                person 4
                person 5
```

**stage 3**

```
  person 3-->   person 1
                person 2
                person 4
                person 5
```

**stage 4**

```
  person 4-->   person 1
                person 2
                person 3
                person 5
```

**stage 5**

```
  person 5-->   person 1
                person 2
                person 3
                person 4
```

I have done my looping for `stage 1`, however for `stage 2` up to `stage 5`, I cannot find how to looping them all together to provide one output that is number acceptace of impostors. My codes for `stage 1` are following below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance
#load dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
#template
data_p1 = dataset[dataset['Person']==1]
y = []
#looping to compare template person 1 and testing person 2 until 37
for x in xrange(2,6):
    #testing
    data_p2 = dataset[dataset['Person']==x]
    #distance function
    dst = distance.euclidean(data_p1 ,data_p2 )
    # example of threshold
    if dst <= 0.05:
        y.append("wrong")

y.count("wrong")
0


dataset.head()
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  Person

    0   1   55  0   10  1
    0   4   87  0   17  2
    0   3   68  0   14  3
    3   7   86  26  14  4
    0   2   82  0   10  5
```

Comment: Mind to share `dataset.head()`?

Comment: @GustavoBezerra I already edited the question, actually that is only the example of dataset.

Comment: @markovzain, what is "distance.euclidean"? is it a standard function or is it yours?

Comment: @markovzain, why do you have duplicates in the "Person" columns? how are you going to do permutations of Persons? it's not quite clear

Comment: @MaxU The distance.euclidean is standard of distance function (from scipy.spatial import distance), and in those data, I have 1 template and 1 testing data for each person, thats why I have duplication in there

Comment: @markovzain, how do you distinguish between template and test data? for example if run: "print(dataset[dataset['Person'] == 8])" against your sample data set it gives me two Persons, so following your algorithm there will be two rows in "data_p1" data frame - is it correct?

Comment: @markovzain, sorry i'm giving up, because i don't understand what and how (algorithm) you want to achieve... I would recommend you to post a full (not cut) dataset for 4-5 persons and expected output dataset - this will help others to understand your question. Beside that i don't understand the following things: 1. AFAIK distance can't be negative, so your condition: (dst <= 0) would be (dst == 0) which means that both points/persons have the same coordinates. So why do you want to calculate euclidean distance then??? 2. what are you going to do with person duplicates?

Comment: I'm baffled at the question but 4 suggestions:  (1) put the `from scipy...` in your code so folks aren't digging thru comments to run your example  (2) expected or desired output would probably help here  (3) you could make your data a lot more compact here, 5 or 6 persons ought to demonstrate the concept just as well as 37  (4) In summary, small but complete dataframe, small but complete code you have tried, small but complete desired output

Comment: @markovzain, and the main thing - you don't want to iterate through your pandas dataset, you want to work with sets of data, not with rows. So i would recommend you to do something similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985401/pandas-compute-series-or-dataframe-permutations

Comment: @MaxU I have edited my question, I am sorry to make you confused

Comment: @markovzain, could you please provide a clear "FAR" algorithm which takes two Persons as arguments and returns "something?" ? And i still don't get it with negative or zero distance condition...

Comment: @MaxU, actually I have a problem in looping process. How I can loop `stage 2` up to `stage 5` without change manually  `data_p1 = dataset[dataset['Person']==1]` and `for x in xrange(2,6)` one by one and return `y.count('wrong')` once

Comment: @markovzain, i've added a loop at the end of my answer - is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is pandas permutation algorithm:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from itertools import permutations
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\s+', index_col=['Person'])
print(df)


idx = list(permutations(df.index, 2))

new = pd.DataFrame(
    {'route' : [
                    [   (df.loc[Ind[0], 'x1'], df.loc[Ind[0], 'x2'], df.loc[Ind[0], 'x3'], df.loc[Ind[0], 'x4'], df.loc[Ind[0], 'x5']),
                        (df.loc[Ind[1], 'x1'], df.loc[Ind[1], 'x2'], df.loc[Ind[1], 'x3'], df.loc[Ind[1], 'x4'], df.loc[Ind[1], 'x5'])
                    ] for Ind in idx
                ]
    },
    index = idx
)

print(new)
```

Output:

```
        x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
Person
1        0   1  55   0  10
2        0   4  87   0  17
3        0   3  68   0  14
4        3   7  86  26  14
5        0   2  82   0  10
                                          route
(1, 2)   [(0, 1, 55, 0, 10), (0, 4, 87, 0, 17)]
(1, 3)   [(0, 1, 55, 0, 10), (0, 3, 68, 0, 14)]
(1, 4)  [(0, 1, 55, 0, 10), (3, 7, 86, 26, 14)]
(1, 5)   [(0, 1, 55, 0, 10), (0, 2, 82, 0, 10)]
(2, 1)   [(0, 4, 87, 0, 17), (0, 1, 55, 0, 10)]
(2, 3)   [(0, 4, 87, 0, 17), (0, 3, 68, 0, 14)]
(2, 4)  [(0, 4, 87, 0, 17), (3, 7, 86, 26, 14)]
(2, 5)   [(0, 4, 87, 0, 17), (0, 2, 82, 0, 10)]
(3, 1)   [(0, 3, 68, 0, 14), (0, 1, 55, 0, 10)]
(3, 2)   [(0, 3, 68, 0, 14), (0, 4, 87, 0, 17)]
(3, 4)  [(0, 3, 68, 0, 14), (3, 7, 86, 26, 14)]
(3, 5)   [(0, 3, 68, 0, 14), (0, 2, 82, 0, 10)]
(4, 1)  [(3, 7, 86, 26, 14), (0, 1, 55, 0, 10)]
(4, 2)  [(3, 7, 86, 26, 14), (0, 4, 87, 0, 17)]
(4, 3)  [(3, 7, 86, 26, 14), (0, 3, 68, 0, 14)]
(4, 5)  [(3, 7, 86, 26, 14), (0, 2, 82, 0, 10)]
(5, 1)   [(0, 2, 82, 0, 10), (0, 1, 55, 0, 10)]
(5, 2)   [(0, 2, 82, 0, 10), (0, 4, 87, 0, 17)]
(5, 3)   [(0, 2, 82, 0, 10), (0, 3, 68, 0, 14)]
(5, 4)  [(0, 2, 82, 0, 10), (3, 7, 86, 26, 14)]
```

Another version where you would have pairs of persons in different columns:

```
new = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a' : [   (df.loc[Ind[0], 'x1'], df.loc[Ind[0], 'x2'], df.loc[Ind[0], 'x3'], df.loc[Ind[0], 'x4'], df.loc[Ind[0], 'x5'])
                for Ind in idx
            ],
     'b' : [   (df.loc[Ind[1], 'x1'], df.loc[Ind[1], 'x2'], df.loc[Ind[1], 'x3'], df.loc[Ind[1], 'x4'], df.loc[Ind[1], 'x5'])
                for Ind in idx
            ]
    },
    index = idx
)
```

Output:

```
                         a                   b
(1, 2)   (0, 1, 55, 0, 10)   (0, 4, 87, 0, 17)
(1, 3)   (0, 1, 55, 0, 10)   (0, 3, 68, 0, 14)
(1, 4)   (0, 1, 55, 0, 10)  (3, 7, 86, 26, 14)
(1, 5)   (0, 1, 55, 0, 10)   (0, 2, 82, 0, 10)
(2, 1)   (0, 4, 87, 0, 17)   (0, 1, 55, 0, 10)
(2, 3)   (0, 4, 87, 0, 17)   (0, 3, 68, 0, 14)
(2, 4)   (0, 4, 87, 0, 17)  (3, 7, 86, 26, 14)
(2, 5)   (0, 4, 87, 0, 17)   (0, 2, 82, 0, 10)
(3, 1)   (0, 3, 68, 0, 14)   (0, 1, 55, 0, 10)
(3, 2)   (0, 3, 68, 0, 14)   (0, 4, 87, 0, 17)
(3, 4)   (0, 3, 68, 0, 14)  (3, 7, 86, 26, 14)
(3, 5)   (0, 3, 68, 0, 14)   (0, 2, 82, 0, 10)
(4, 1)  (3, 7, 86, 26, 14)   (0, 1, 55, 0, 10)
(4, 2)  (3, 7, 86, 26, 14)   (0, 4, 87, 0, 17)
(4, 3)  (3, 7, 86, 26, 14)   (0, 3, 68, 0, 14)
(4, 5)  (3, 7, 86, 26, 14)   (0, 2, 82, 0, 10)
(5, 1)   (0, 2, 82, 0, 10)   (0, 1, 55, 0, 10)
(5, 2)   (0, 2, 82, 0, 10)   (0, 4, 87, 0, 17)
(5, 3)   (0, 2, 82, 0, 10)   (0, 3, 68, 0, 14)
(5, 4)   (0, 2, 82, 0, 10)  (3, 7, 86, 26, 14)
```

If i understood your looping correctly (i'm not sure that i got it):

```
for x in range(1, 6):
    for y in range(1, 6):
        if x!=y:
            print(x,y)
```

NOTE: but you **definitely** don't want to use this approach with pandas!